# What is that yellow square to the right of the main entry door of this Lufthansa A350?

Tags: feature-identification, airbus-a350, paint, livery, lufthansa

My question is: is it just part of the paint job, or does this yellow square serve a purpose? I haven't seen this square on any other airlines.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a yellow square that says Willkommen / Welcome. In one case I have seen that additional text was written into the square with a black (removable?) marker.

[image: Picture of the yellow square]

<sub>[Source](https://medium.com/@pyok/yawn-lufthansa-officially-unveils-its-new-brand-image-melon-yellow-colour-will-remain-2e7edf998ce2)</sub>

[This website explains it](https://adammmarsh.com/creativejournal/lufthansa) like this:

> A yellow welcome panel painted beside each of the passenger boarding
> doors is now visible on each aircraft. The mark is a flat yellow
> rectangle, with the word 'welcome' in both German and English,
> accompanied by the iconic logo in the corner. What I love so much
> about this - is that that bright yellow warmth is presented to every
> passenger, right as they board every aircraft. Upon boarding, each
> passenger is welcomed, setting the stage for the onboard experience
> and hospitality that will follow. The crew can write personalised
> messages to give a more human welcome to this otherwise mechanical
> setting.

Comment: "bright yellow warmth is presented to every passenger" - yeah right. That's marketing for you...

Comment: "Bright yellow warmth" doesn't project much to me, but I tell ya' what, service & comfort on my transatlantic flight on Lufthansa to Germany was _much_ better than the return flight service on a United aircraft. Even though they're both part of the same alliance.

Comment: @user253751 The door may have been designed by the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation. Share and Enjoy!

Comment: So it's a yellow whiteboard...

Comment: @jcaron: A yellowboard!